# Determining Device Type in prefix.pch

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am building a universal app and have included the following macro in prefix.pch to help with quick identification of the device type in classes:

```
#define IS_IPAD UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

I am confused as to why this works. My understanding is that prefix.pch is pre-compiled and therefore the value of the IS_IPAD variable is set at compile time rather than run time, so it seems the value will therefore always be for the device against which the app was compiled? Or is a univeral app compiled for both iPhone and iPad?

Comment: You're absolutely right about it being a compile-time constant, which should, in turn, give you the answer you seek: that universal compilation produces "fat" binaries.

Comment: @CodaFi Does your comment contradict the answer below?

Comment: Compile-Time constants are compile-time constants.  It's possible apple does runtime checking, but then again, it's also possible that it's merely a flag that's set when the compiler generates the fat binary.  Nobody really knows without seeing the IMP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are like global search and replace during compile. When you compile, every instance of `IS_IPAD` is literally replaced with `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` as part of the preprocessing. Then the file is compiled.

So you end up with the desired runtime check in your code. The use of this macro only makes for less typing by you.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I did not appreciate that IS_IPAD would be replaced, I just thought its value at compile time was stored.